# CSS to display the image wihout using img tag in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS. I just want to place an image before the chapter title. I have an arrow image and I want to place that image before the chapter name, only using CSS and without using the HTML `<img>` tag.

**My Code:**

```css
.body > .ce_label:before{
  background: url("arrow.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="body-proof" class="body top-most bottom-most">
  <div id="OPT_ID_4224-proof" class="ce_label">
    Chapter<span class="tb"></span>11<span class="te"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not getting the correct output with design. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: `:before` pseudo element works when you mention `content` property. Add `content: "";`. And also by defaulty, pseudo elements are `display: inline`, change it to `display: block` and apply some dimensions in which the image should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below css for this

```
.ce_label:before{
  content: url(arrow.png);
}
```

Comment: The above css displays nothing. @Khunteta

Comment: @malar You need to check image path is correct or not in you code..
if not then you need to give relative path..

Answer (score 1):

Use 'content' property with pseudo elements like before/after and Make sure your image path is correct.
check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9a1j8u9y/1/)

```
.body > .ce_label:before {
  content: url(https://s14.postimg.org/zfkdt9wdt/down_arrow.png);
}
```